# ffmpeg concatenate videos and then merge with an audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a few video files without any audio. I want to concatenate these videos to create a single video and then add a sound track (an mp3 file) to it. Currently I am doing it in two phases -

First concatenate videos...

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [1:v:0] [2:v:0] concat=n=3:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 concat_video.mp4
```

and then add audio...

```
ffmpeg -y -i concat_video.mp4 -i sound_track.mp3 -shortest output.mp4
```

This produces fairly good output but it takes considerable amount of time. 
I was wondering if there could be a single ffmpeg command that would do both and save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add your audio input and `-map` it:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i video3.mp4 -i sound_track.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:v:0] [1:v:0] [2:v:0] concat=n=3:v=1:a=0 [v]" -map "[v]" -map 3:a -c:v libx264 -shortest output.mp4
```